# ¿Cómo guardar una imagen en MongoDb que corre sobre Azure?

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-storage

Buen día;

Estoy intentando guardar una imagen en azure en una base de datos MongoDb, localmente me funciona, pero cuando desplegue el sitio en Azure ya no.

Lo que estoy haciendo en usar MongoGridFS de la siguiente manera:

```
    public Guid SaveImage(ImagenDto file)
    {
        try
        {
            var createOptions = new MongoGridFSCreateOptions()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                ContentType = file.ContentType
            };
            _mongoDatabase.GridFS.Upload(file.InputStream, file.FileName, createOptions);
            return createOptions.Id.AsGuid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogExcepcion(ex);
            return Guid.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto la linea .Upload me arroja el siguiente mensaje: element 'md5' not found.

Encontre en este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546343/azure-storage-calculated-md5-does-not-match-existing-property y dice que debo cambiar la propiedad MD5validation, la cual investigando en MongoDB es:

```
_mongoDatabase.GridFS.Settings.VerifyMD5
```

Pero al tratar de cambiar, me arroja un mensaje diciendo que la BD esta congelada.

```
 _mongoDatabase.GridFS.Settings.IsFrozen
```

Esta propiedad es de solo lectura por lo cual no se como cambiar la propiedad VerifyMD5.

Agradezco su ayuda si alguien sabe cómo almacenar las imagenes en Azure.

Comment: Que controlador usas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus using

```
 using MongoDB.Bson;
 using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
 using MongoDB.Driver;
 using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;
 using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

Los datos de conexión

```
 protected static IMongoClient clienteLocal = new MongoClient();
 protected static IMongoDatabase dataLocal = clienteLocal.GetDatabase("tubase");
```

Dentro del metodo click de tu botón

```
 GridFSBucketOptions o = new GridFSBucketOptions();
 o.BucketName = "data";
 GridFSBucket fsbucket = new GridFSBucket(dataLocal, o);
```

Fijate que en esta parte se hace uso de [GridFs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) el cual de manera "Magica" crea dos colecciones una llamata data.fs.files y la otra data.fs.chunks en la fs.files son los datos de tu archivo que deseas subir, aqui es donde se guarda el MD5  de tu archivo mientras que en el data.chunks esta el binario dividido en 16mb

Para cargar tu imagen,foto,video etc. puedas usar:

```
 MemoryStream ms_photo = new MemoryStream();
 pictureBoxPhoto.Image.Save(ms_photo, ImageFormat.Png);
 byte[] byte_photo = ms_photo.ToArray();
 ObjectId id = fsbucket.UploadFromBytes("3", byte_photo);
```

Como vez se intenta cargar una foto de la camara que muestra un pictureBox en esta parte se utiliza UploadFromBytes pero puedes usar UploadFromStream en donde la cargas desde tu directorio; Ejemplo:

```
 FileStream file = File.OpenRead("ruta_archivo");
 ObjectId id = fsbucket.UploadFromStream("1", file);
```

En esta parte la idea es cargar un archivo del directorio, donde "1" representa el nombre que tendra en nuestra coleccion en el objeto filename